# Finding conjugacy classes

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I've been having problems with finding conjugacy classes. I don't really understand how to do it properly.

Say we look at a S3 group: $S_3=]e, (12), (13), (23), (123), (132)]$

If we look at just $(12)$ first:

$e(12)e^{-1} = e(12)e=(12)$ I can understand this.

$(12)(12)(12)^{-1} = (12)(12)(12) = (12)$ Now here I'm a little confused. Wouldn't $(12)^{-1} = (21)$?

Then $(13)(12)(13)^{-1} = (13)(12)(13) = (32)$ how did that become $(32)$?

I thought you would start from the right so do $(12)(13)$ first then that would be $(123)$ then $(13)(123)$: 1 stays the same. 3 goes to 2? then 3 stays so (123)? I'm really confused

Comment: $(12) = (21)$.  They're both the permutation that switches $1$ and $2$.

Comment: You need to be able to recognize when two written cycles represent the same permutation. For instance, (12345), (23451), (34512), (45123), (51234) are all the same permutation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(12) and (21) are the same permutation.

As for (13)(12)(13), well, simply compute what it does to 1,2,3:

- (13)(12)(13)1=(13)(12)3=(13)3=1
- (13)(12)(13)2=(13)(12)2=(13)1=3
- (13)(12)(13)3=(13)(12)1=(13)2=2

So (13)(12)(13) leaves 1 fixed, and swaps 2 and 3.

Also, (12)(13) is not (123). Check:

- (12)(13)1=(12)3=3
- (12)(13)2=(12)2=1
- (12)(13)3=(12)1=2

Thus, (12)(13) sends 1 to 3, and 3 to 2, and 2 to 1. So (12)(13)=(132), not (123).

Answer (score 1):

$(12)$ and $(21)$ are the same permutation (which maps $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $1$, and leaves everything else unchanged).

Likewise, $(13)(12)(13) = (23)$ because it maps $2$ to $3$, $3$ to $2$ and leaves everything else unchanged (including $1$). Also, $(12)(13) = (132)$, not $(123)$.

Comment: Then what about $(123)^{-1}$? I would say that would be $(321)$ but the answer is $(132)$ So the inverse is not the inverse of the permutation??

Comment: $(321)$ and $(132)$ are the same permutation.

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion is coming from the composition of permutations. Here is an example
suppose we want to know $(1 \, 2 \, 3)( 1\, 3)$. Then we start from the rightmost cycle, i.e. $(1 \, 3)$. Here $1$ goes to $3$, then we consider the next cycle to the left, here $3$ goes to $1$, so we will conclude that the $1$ (from the rightmost cycle) goes to $1$ (because $1 \to 3 \to 1$).
Now we consider $3$ from the rightmost cycle, this $3$ goes to $1$, then in the left cycle $1$ goes to $2$, thus $3$ goes to $2$. So we have
$$(1 \, 2 \, 3)( 1\, 3)=(1)(3 \, 2)=(3 \, 2).$$
Once you get this then conjugacy will become easier to handle.

Comment: Do we always start from the right or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @Kennan think of it as function composition $f(g(x))$. We will start with $g$ and then $f$, likewise we have to start from the rightmost and then work towards left.

Comment: so let's see if I've got this right... if it's for $(13)(132)$, starting from the right cycle. $1->3->2$ then we look at left cycle, there's no 2 so 2 remains? or do we go $1->3->2->1$ then from left cycle $1->3$ but then I'll still need a 2 somewhere...

Comment: @Kennan (13)(132)1=(13)3=1 and (13)(132)2=(13)1=3 and (13)(132)3=(13)2=2. So (13)(132) sends 1 to 1, 2 to 3, and 3 to 2. Thus (13)(132)=(23).

Comment: okay one more attempt: $(23)(12)(23)^{-1} = (23)(12)(23)$ then $(23)(12)(23)1=(23)(12)1=(23)2=3$, $(23)(12)(23)2=(23)(12)3=(23)3=2$ and $(23)(12)(23)3=(23)(12)2=(23)1=1$ so $(23)(12)(23)=(13)$. Is that right?

Comment: @Kennan Yes that's right.